# Unable to open the physical file. Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sqlconnection

I am trying to work on a query to attach a database (UNC path) remotely.
I have SQL Server management studio (SSMS) installed in SQL Server machine (machineSQL) and also in another machine (machineRemote) in same domain.

Query::

```
CREATE DATABASE "simpleData" ON 
(FILENAME = '\\machineRemote\ShareName\sample\sample_database.mdf'),
(FILENAME = '\\machineRemote\ShareName\sample\sample_database_log.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

If i run the query in SSMS on machineSQL. The database gets attached successfully.
But if i run it in SSMS on machineRemote it throws an error like :

```
Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 1
Unable to open the physical file "\\machineRemote\ShareName\sample\sample_database.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
Msg 1802, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

NOTE : The issue is occurring only if windows authentication is used to log in SSMS. SQL Server authentication works just fine.

Need help on this.

Comment: Open SSMS in admin mode and try it once.

Comment: @KViswagna I tried in admin mode. It did not work.

Comment: The account under which your SQL Server is running should have RW access to this destination.

Comment: @gofr1 I have checked the RW permission on the destination and it is still not working.

Comment: If you create a database using one sql instance, and now you try to create another database which points to already used files you will get this error message as well.

Comment: @gofr1 I understand your point. But I am not trying to attach already used files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate Full Control permission for the user to the mdf and ldf files.
Check the screenshot below.
[image]

Hope it helps.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/105605/unable-to-open-the-physical-file-operating-system.html